# Slowly varying functions and the direction of convergence

Tags: asymptotics, extreme-value-analysis, slowly-varying-functions

Consider a slowly varying function $L(n)$ and let $\lambda > 0$. Is it true that there exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

\begin{align}
\frac{L(\lambda n)}{L(n)} \geq 1
\end{align}
for all $n \geq N$? And, if not, are there any conditions under which this holds true?

Answer (score 3):

It is not true: consider $L(x) = \log(x)$, then for $n\geq 3$ we have that

$$
\dfrac{L(\lambda n)}{L(n)} = \dfrac{\log(\lambda)}{\log(n)} + 1 < 1
$$

if $\lambda\in(0,1)$. I am not aware of conditions in order for what you want to be true.